# How to stop excel from formating DATETIME to DATE

Tags: microsoft-excel, ms-sql, vb.net, ssis

Im trying to insert DATETIME data from MSSQL database with SSIS into excel destination but upon inserting, excel formats it to DATE by its own.. Data in table are DATETIME.

In Excel i tried to format columns as Custom, put dummy hidden row with datetime format with no success..

In SSIS i tried to change in advanced editor put False in ValidateExternalMetadata and setting data type in External columns to DT_DBTIMESTAMP with no success.

I tried to do it in VB.net script task, but as im going to deploy it on server i cant use excel.interop or other library to manipulate excel..

I need to preserve type as datetime for reporting i cant put it into string.
But Excel always change my DATETIME(yyyy.mm.dd hh:mm:ss) to DATE(yyyy.mm.dd) format..

I dont know what else i can do. All help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to [Undo automatic formatting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/undo-automatic-formatting-in-excel-54eba206-110c-445a-89f1-c4eb67a36bd4).

Comment: Paste Values only?

Comment: Have you tried to add Data Conversion in your Data Flow Task?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim ExcelApp As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
ExcelApp.Range("A1","A100").NumberFormat = "@"
```

you can also define date format for date columns

```
 ExcelApp.Range("A1","A100").NumberFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
```